# Ways to change Windows Login

Tags: windows-10, login

I'm thinking of changing the way of logging into Windows. I currently am using a 4 digit pin, which I've already told a lot of people if they needed my pc just to google some quick things.

**My idea would be to have the pin always be the last three digits of the current time**, so noone would really know my pin / can read it from my fingers.

Does anyone know of a program which helps me do something like this

Comment: How about turning on the Guest Account. They can't save changes. So whatever they do deletes as soon as they log off. `net users guest /active`. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/local-accounts

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com  may help you find an answer more expeditiously.

Comment: Strictly speaking what you want isn’t possible, however, Windows 10 supports OTP authentication through Windows Hello.  [Example](https://yubikey.me/windows/).  OTP codes of course are based on the current time.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, the PIN is only changed in the Windows 10 Account Setup. There is not a minute by minute policy way of changing it. I do not give my Windows password / PIN to anyone; rather I put information others need in a common area accessible by their own user name